# Connecting to database engine again when a new query or running view

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-engine

When I connect to a server [image]

via SSMS, I can connect fine albeit a slow.

When I click on a new query or try to run a view in a database on this server, the same prompt comes up but with everything greyed out and then after a while the prompt disappears and the view runs or new query tab opens:

[image]

It's like SSMS is trying to connect to the server again every time I run something or even when clicking new query.  How do I stop this prompt appearing?

Comment: Hello Randi, v.17.6.  SQL server 2016.

Comment: the IT team do all the setting up but unfortunately they don't have an actual DBA and I'm an end user.  The server is a cloud server - Azure - however, we do have a networked one, which connects pretty much instantaneously and no prompt!  We're replacing the networked one with Azure.

Answer (score 3):

> It's like SSMS is trying to connect to the server again every time I run something or even when clicking new query.

That's because it is. That's how it works, each connection is a new connection. The *initial* connection dialog you see if for object explorer. Each open "new query" tab is its own connection.

> How do I stop this prompt appearing?

It's appearing because there is either very high network latency or the pre-login/login times are long. Almost always it's due to very bad latency/undersized vms. Check your network round trip time to the server and check that the server is under heavy load or undersized.

Adding in [Aaron's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) comments which are also on point:

> Could also be a not-very-efficient logon trigger or an expensive
>   resource governor classifier function on that server (connecting via a
>   local SSMS on the VM might rule this out). The error log might yield
>   some clues too, or an extended events session that captures
>   connection/log in information.